# Track changes on worksheet, copy active cell change Column Header & NewColumnValue

Tags: excel, vba, events, target, worksheet-function

REF: Track changes on worksheet, copy cell that is not the active cell in active cell row and record value

I have revamped my worksheet and hoping to get insight to how to get values in cells upon change event of...

- **NewColumn__Value** - currently none are pulling correct value.  active cell impacts results and want pre & post event change to compare later. i know it is currenlly outputting the same as the corresponding OldVColumn_Value, but left in to help with conveying of ask.
- **ColumnHeader** - currently not pulling any value. header is in 2nd row of 'target.value

any thoughts on code consolidation is greatly appreciated. to  i'm forced to do 'long division' approach and so great to see how to get to 'calculator' approach, helps me learn.

```
Option Explicit
Public OldValue, OldColumnJValue, ColumnHeaderX, ColumnJValue, ColumnHeader, OldColumnJJValue, 
OldColumnJKValue, OldColumnJLValue, OldColumnJMValue, NewColumnJJValue, NewColumnJKValue, 
NewColumnJLValue, NewColumnJMValue, OldColumnMPValue, OldColumnMQValue, OldColumnMRValue, 
OldColumnMSValue, NewColumnMPValue, NewColumnMQValue, NewColumnMRValue, NewColumnMSValue, 
OldColumnPVValue, OldColumnPWValue, OldColumnPXValue, OldColumnPYValue, NewColumnPVValue, 
NewColumnPWValue, NewColumnPXValue, NewColumnPYValue

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            .Offset(1, 0) = ActiveSheet.Name
            .Offset(1, 1) = Target.Address(0, 0)
            .Offset(1, 2) = Environ("username")
            .Offset(1, 3) = Now
                'add empl name vlookup formula to this column?
            .Offset(1, 5) = ColumnJValue
            **.Offset(1, 6) = ColumnHeader**
            .Offset(1, 7) = OldValue
            .Offset(1, 8) = Target
                '2020 pre-change value below
            .Offset(1, 9) = OldColumnJJValue
            .Offset(1, 10) = OldColumnJKValue
            .Offset(1, 11) = OldColumnJLValue
            .Offset(1, 12) = OldColumnJMValue
                '2020 post-change value below
            **.Offset(1, 13) = NewColumnJJValue
            .Offset(1, 14) = NewColumnJKValue
            .Offset(1, 15) = NewColumnJLValue
            .Offset(1, 16) = NewColumnJMValue**
                '2021 pre-change value below
            .Offset(1, 18) = OldColumnMPValue
            .Offset(1, 19) = OldColumnMQValue
            .Offset(1, 20) = OldColumnMRValue
            .Offset(1, 21) = OldColumnMSValue
                '2021 post-change value below
            **.Offset(1, 22) = NewColumnMPValue
            .Offset(1, 23) = NewColumnMQValue
            .Offset(1, 24) = NewColumnMRValue
            .Offset(1, 25) = NewColumnMSValue**
                '2022 pre-change value below
            .Offset(1, 27) = OldColumnPVValue
            .Offset(1, 28) = OldColumnPWValue
            .Offset(1, 29) = OldColumnPXValue
            .Offset(1, 30) = OldColumnPYValue
                '2022 post-change value below
            **.Offset(1, 31) = NewColumnPVValue
            .Offset(1, 32) = NewColumnPWValue
            .Offset(1, 33) = NewColumnPXValue
            .Offset(1, 34) = NewColumnPYValue**
        End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        OldValue = Target
           'Program name changed
        ColumnJValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 10)
           'Column header of changed cell
        **ColumnHeader = Range("A1")(Target.Row, (2, 0)**
           '2020 pre-change value below
        OldColumnJJValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 270)
        OldColumnJKValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 271)
        OldColumnJLValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 272)
        OldColumnJMValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 273)
           '2020 post-change value below
        **NewColumnJJValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 270)
        NewColumnJKValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 271)
        NewColumnJLValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 272)
        NewColumnJMValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 273)**
           '2021 pre-change value below
        OldColumnMPValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 354)
        OldColumnMQValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 355)
        OldColumnMRValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 356)
        OldColumnMSValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 357)
           '2021 post-change value below
        **NewColumnMPValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 354)
        NewColumnMQValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 355)
        NewColumnMRValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 356)
        NewColumnMSValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 367)**
           '2022 pre-change value below
        OldColumnPVValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 438)
        OldColumnPWValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 439)
        OldColumnPXValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 440)
        OldColumnPYValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 441)
           '2022 post-change value below
        **NewColumnPVValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 438)
        NewColumnPWValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 439)
        NewColumnPXValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 440)
        NewColumnPYValue = Range("A1")(Target.Row, 441)**
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MsgBox "Multiple cell selections are not allowed on this sheet", vbCritical
    ActiveCell.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but I'd probably try to use a dictionary instead of the long list of variables, and loop through that where possible.

Comment: Basically asking 2 things..  

First, when the active cell changes, say R13, it impacts other cells values in that row.  I want to copy these values and put into logdetails ws.  Everything is good with getting the old pre-change values from Col JJ13:JM13, MP13:MS13 & PV13:PY13 (etc) but also want to record the post-change values of those same cells.  The change in R13 impacts these cells and I want to record pre/post change values.  Then output on the logdetails tab with other values.

Second, where there is an active cell change, record the ColumnHeader, located in row 2

Comment: If every change is recorded at its new value there is no need to record the previous value as well at that time because it's already in the log, recorded when it was last changed.

Comment: i believe i follow you.  yes ive tried to use these values when the next cell is changed.  i cannot get the values placed on the correct row, where it needs to be for later analysis.  it need to be shifted up 1 row.  its want to put all data into logdetails on same row no matter what row offset i change them to.

Comment: i was able to use old values in another approach, so i am good .  thanks for all the insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad to learn from your comment that you solved your problem. Well done! I did think your tackling the task quite heroic and don't wish to either throw away my work, nor deprive you of its possible benefits. Please take gander.

```
Option Explicit

Private PrevVal(1)  As Variant      ' previously selected row data
                                    ' PrevVal(0) = row number, PrevVal(1) = row's data
Enum Nws                            ' data tab (ActiveSheet)
    ' 147
    NwsHeaderRow = 2                ' change to suit (data start immediately below this row)
    NwsClmJ = 10                    ' Debug.Print Columns("J").Column
    NwsClmJJ = 270
    NwsClmJK                        ' no assigned value means preceding + 1
    NwsClmJL
    NwsClmJM
    NwsClmMP = 354
    NwsClmMQ
    NwsClmMR
    NwsClmMS
    NwsClmPV = 438
    NwsClmPW
    NwsClmPX
    NwsClmPY
    NwsTop                      ' defining the last used column
End Enum

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' 147
    SetPrevVal ActiveCell.Row
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 147
    SetPrevVal Target.Row
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 147
    
    Dim TriggerRange    As Range        ' range of relevant changes
    Dim MsgTxt()        As String       ' error message
    Dim Log(1 To 34)    As Variant      ' Log entry
    Dim Employee        As String       ' employee's name (retrieved by VLOOKUP)
    Dim i               As Long         ' index of Log()
    
    Set TriggerRange = Range(Cells(NwsHeaderRow + 1, 1), _
                             Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
                             .Resize(, NwsTop - 1)
                             Debug.Print TriggerRange.Address
    With Target
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, TriggerRange) Is Nothing Then
            If .Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
                MsgTxt = Split("Please change only one cell at a time on this sheet." & _
                             "|Unsupported user action", "|")
            Else
                If IsEmpty(PrevVal) Then
                    MsgTxt = Split("?")
                ElseIf PrevVal(0) <> .Row Then
                    MsgTxt = Split("?")
                End If
                If Join(MsgTxt) = "?" Then
                    MsgTxt = Split("Sorry, I lost the previous record." & vbCr & _
                                   "Please repeat the action." & _
                                 "|Internal error", "|")
                End If
            End If
            If Len(Join(MsgTxt)) Then
                MsgBox MsgTxt(0), vbCritical, MsgTxt(1)
                Application.Undo
                .Select
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            Employee = ""        ' add empl name vlookup formula here
            For i = 1 To 8
                Log(i) = Array(Environ("username"), Employee, Now, _
                               ActiveSheet.Name, Cells(.Row, NwsClmJ).Value, _
                               .Address(0, 0), PrevVal(1)(1, .Column), _
                               .Value)(i - 1)
            Next i
            
            For i = 9 To 12
                Log(i) = PrevVal(1)(1, NwsClmJJ + i - 9)
                Log(i + 4) = Cells(.Row, NwsClmJJ + i - 9).Value
            Next i
            ' column 17 remains blank by your design
            
            For i = 18 To 21
                Log(i) = PrevVal(1)(1, NwsClmMP + i - 18)
                Log(i + 4) = Cells(.Row, NwsClmMP + i - 18).Value
            Next i
            ' column 26 remains blank by your design
            
            For i = 27 To 30
                Log(i) = PrevVal(1)(1, NwsClmPV + i - 27)
                Log(i + 4) = Cells(.Row, NwsClmPV + i - 27).Value
            Next i
        
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                .ScreenUpdating = False
            End With
            
            With Worksheets("Log")
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) _
                       .Resize(1, UBound(Log)).Value = Log
            End With
                
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = True
                .ScreenUpdating = True
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Function SetPrevVal(ByVal R As Long) As Range
    ' 147
    
    Dim Rl      As Long         ' last used row in column [270]
    
    ' presuming that column 1 offers a relevant measurement
    Rl = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' don't record if the selection is in or above the caption row (NwsHeaderRow)
    ' or below the data range as defined by the end of 'FirstCl'
    ' you might add an exception for columns < `NwsClmJJ` ??
    If (R > NwsHeaderRow) And (R <= Rl) Then
        PrevVal(0) = R
        ' presuming that there is a header for every column in Header Row
        PrevVal(1) = DataRange(R).Value
    End If
End Function

Private Function DataRange(ByVal R As Long) As Range
    ' 147
    
    ' presuming that there is a header for every column in the Header Row
    Set DataRange = Range(Cells(R, 1), Cells(NwsHeaderRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) _
                          .Offset(R - NwsHeaderRow))
End Function
```

For lack of data, I did some very limited testing on this code: It does create a log entry, largely along the lines your code appears to suggest. Once you get the hang of it it's as transparent as your own, which gives me hope that you will be able to follow it and, for example, insert the missing Employee Name. It's very easy to add date or columns, and it's much faster than what you had. There are quite a few comments too, which should prove helpful.

One word about the "old" values. I replaced your many public variables with a single array which records ***all*** data in one row. It does so when the sheet is loaded (activated) and thereafter on every click. If, by whatever reason (which mostly happen during testing) the array isn't available or the wrong array is available the user will be prompted to repeat his change. It's rather watertight.

Comment: wow, thank you...!  i will certainly dig in with this.  worth the hands on learning!

Comment: this is certainly a quicker logging of the data approach.  i put in a new excel doc with data, program worked almost seamlessly.  i had to remove the if counterlarge argument portion.  it worked when multiple selection of blank cell  manipulation, but when you did with actual multiple cells of data, it errors out.  the other is does the NwsHeaderRow display?  i cannot locate output on either ws.  thanks for any further insights.

Comment: I have modified my code to use `Target.Cells.CountLarge` instead of `Target.CountLarge`. None of the enumerations are displayed in the worksheet. They serve to give names to numbers and these names are used throughout the code in place of the hard numbers. E.g. *NwsHeaderRow = 2* because your header row is in sheet row 2. If you were to move it to row 1 or 3 you may simply change the value assigned to the *NwsHeaderRow* enumeration and the rest of the code will adapt to the change automatically.

Comment: BTW, I believe not all of the names given in the Enum were, in fact, finally used in the code. This is easy to clean up if it bothers you. I left it untouched because it shows the logic implemented in the Enum.

Comment: ive been able to get the counterlarge arguments (messaging) to work properly.  i am going to look at the NwsHeaderRow display location next.  i like the direction this code is taking me, any further insights would be welcomed.

Comment: When you read up on enums (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/enum-statement) you will find that the name of my enum is *Nws*. Therefore the first enumeration could be `HeaderRow = 2`. The code could refer to this number simply as `HeaderRow.`. I don't like that because *HeaderRow* would be a variable or a range object in my codes. I also don't like to use the full name of the enumeration `Nws.HeaderRow` because, again, the period denotes something else. So I name it Nws.NwsHeaderRow` but never use the full name.

Comment: thanks interesting read.  i wanted to output & show the HeaderRow value on the log ws.  i have been able to display this value, so looks like im good with the code now.  thanks for all the help and insights.  should i approve this answer for you?